# Using npm dependencies in Kotlin/Js

Tags: javascript, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js, kotlin-js-interop

I need to generate uuid in Kotlin/JS and looking to call [uuid.v4()](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/blob/main/src/v4.js) from Kotlin/JS. I have gone through the documentation - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/using-packages-from-npm.html and https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-modules.html but somehow cannot figure out how to invoke.

What I did is this -

1. Included uuid as an npm dependency in JsMain sourceset

```
val jsMain by getting {
    dependencies {
        implementation(npm("uuid", "9.0.0"))
    }
}
```

2. In JsMain, created a uuid.kt file with this content

```
@JsModule("uuid")
@JsNonModule
external fun v4(options: Any?, buf: Any?, offset: Any?): String
```

3. In Kotlin/Js code, calling `v4(null, null, null)` doesn't works.

I get this error in console -

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: v4 is not defined
```

Comment: You need to mention the module using `@JsModule("uuid")`

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention in the question that I also added @JsModule("uuid"), edited the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it will work -

1. declare uuid as an nmp dependency in JsMain sourceSet in build.gradle.kts

```
val jsMain by getting {
    dependencies {
        implementation(npm("uuid", "9.0.0"))
    }
}
```

2. In JsMain, create a uuid.kt file with contents

```
@JsModule("uuid")
@JsNonModule
external val uuid: dynamic
```

3. From Kotlin/Js, use it like

```
uuid.v4()
```